# log being spammed with TextView SYANI Clipboard API

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, logcat

My app functions fine but from time my log is spammed with this:

```
25508-25508/[MY APP PACKAGE NAME] D/TextView: SYANI: Clipboard API is calling: unregisterClipboardEventListener()
25508-25508/[MY APP PACKAGE NAME] D/TextView: SYANI: Clipboard API is calling: clearFilter()
25508-25508/[MY APP PACKAGE NAME] D/TextView: SYANI: Clipboard API is calling: unregisterClipboardEventListener()
25508-25508/[MY APP PACKAGE NAME] D/TextView: SYANI: Clipboard API is calling: clearFilter()
25508-25508/[MY APP PACKAGE NAME] D/TextView: SYANI: Clipboard API is calling: unregisterClipboardEventListener()
25508-25508/[MY APP PACKAGE NAME] D/TextView: SYANI: Clipboard API is calling: clearFilter()
```

My app uses a lot of `EditText` with `OnFocusChangedListeners` and `TextWatchers`, could this be the cause? What exactly is causing it and should I do something about it or ignore it?

Comment: did you find out what's making it happen?